# Numbers between 0.25 and 0.75 of quartiles in a vector MATLAB

Tags: matlab, quantile

I have a vector of simple numbers such as:

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

I would like to have all the numbers of the vector that fall in between  [25% 75%] quartiles. However, when I use the command below:

```
quantile(a,[0.25 0.75])
```

It only gives me 2 numbers of 2 and 6 (instead of 3,4,5,6). 
Do you have any solution how I can do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the mathematical definition of a [quantile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile), the [`quantile()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantile.html) function should **not** be returning `{3,4,5,6}` given `[0.25 0.75]`.

A quantile of `a` may be thought of as the inverse of the [cumulative distribution function (CDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) for `a`. Since the CDF F<sub>a</sub>(x) = P(a ≤ x)  is a right-continuous increasing function, its inverse F<sub>a</sub><sup>-1</sup>(q) will be a one-to-one function as well.

Thus `quantile(0.25)` can only return a single value (scalar), the smallest value `x` such that P(a ≤ x) = 0.25.

However, **logical indexing** will do the trick.  See code below.

```
% MATLAB R2017a
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
Q = quantile(a,[0.25 0.75]) % returns 25th & 75th quantiles of a
aQ = a(a>=Q(1) & a<=Q(2))   % returns elements of a between 25th & 75th quantiles (inclusive)
```